# AngularJS filter returning html as string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I've created an AngularJS filter to automatically create clickable links from addresses found in data. The filter:

```
app.filter('parseUrl', function() {
    var  //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
        replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim,
        //URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
        replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim,
        //Change email addresses to mailto:: links.
        replacePattern3 = /(\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/gim;

        return function(text, target, otherProp) {        
            angular.forEach(text.match(replacePattern1), function(url) {
                text = text.replace(replacePattern1, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>");
            });
            angular.forEach(text.match(replacePattern2), function(url) {
                text = text.replace(replacePattern2, "$1<a href=\"http://$2\" target=\"_blank\">$2</a>");
            });
            angular.forEach(text.match(replacePattern3), function(url) {
                text = text.replace(replacePattern3, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>");
            });

            return text;        
        };
    });
```

And here is how I'm calling it (inside a paragraph):

```
<p><strong>Details:</strong> {{event.description | parseUrl}}</p>
```

And this works correctly to replace the plain text links with the code for a link. However, it replaces it with the link literally as plain text. For example, `www.google.com` would get replaced with `&lt;a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"&gt;http://google.com&lt;/a&gt;`. This clearly doesn't make a clickable link, which was my goal.

I'm not sure why this is happening. Any ideas on how to prevent/fix it? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the "linky" filter AngularJS provides (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.filter:linky) in the ngSanitize module -- that filter may already do what you need, and the documentation for it supports the suggestions made in the answers regarding the ng-bind-html / ng-bind-html-unsafe directives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the [ngBindHtmlUnsafe](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe) directive to have the HTML that your filter produces applied as actual innerHTML contents of an element, like so:

```
<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="event.description | parseUrl"></span>
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such directive in new version of AngularJS

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` as it will bring potential security risks. I think this was one of the reasons why it was deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use either:

- [ngBindHtmlUnsafe](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe)
  If you 100% trust the source of the content
- [ngBindHtml](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.directive:ngBindHtml)
  If you don't trust the source of the content

Outputting a string using an expression will escape any html entities that you pass to it (symbols such as < > &)

Answer (score 1):

I was using this filter for a while, somehow without noticing the disastrous results it produced.  My modified version here:

```
filter('parseUrl', function($sce) {
var  //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
    replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim,
    //URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
    replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim,
    //Change email addresses to mailto:: links.
    replacePattern3 = /(\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/gim;

    return function(text, target, otherProp) {        
        text = (text + '').replace(/>/,"&gt;").replace(/</,"&lt;");
        text = (text + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1<br>$2');
        text = text.replace(replacePattern1, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>");
        text = text.replace(replacePattern2, "<a href=\"http://$2\" target=\"_blank\">$2</a>");
        text = text.replace(replacePattern3, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>");
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
});
```

Notice that it's not using angular.forEach!  (?????)  The output would go ballistic when it did.  Presumably this problem has to do with having multiple matches!

Comment: Instead of the one in my main question, I actually ended up using a fork of it: https://gist.github.com/meenie/6018010